# How to Understand the Gambler Ruin Problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, gambling

I'm reading the probability chapter from an interview book called A Practical Guide to Quantitative Finance Interview, and cannot make sense or understand one of the problems called "Gambler Ruin Problem" (4.3 Conditional Probability and Bayes' Formula":

A gambler start with an initial fortune of i dollars. On each successive game, the gambler wins 1 dollar with probability p, or loses 1 dollar with probability q = 1-p. He will stop if he either accumulates N dollars or loses all his money. What is the probability that he will end up with N dollars?

Here is the solution:

From any initial state i(the dollars the gambler has), let $P(i)$ be the probability that the gambler's fortune will reach N instead of 0. The next state is either $i+1$ with probability p or i-1 with probability q. So we have:

$P(i) = pP(i+1) + qP(i-1)$

Could any expert explain why the above equation holds?

Comment: Just use simple conditioning (Bayes' theorem)

Comment: He starts with $i$, so his probability of reaching $N$ is $p(i)$. He gambles the first time. With prob $p$ he gains 1 after which his prob of reaching $N$ is $p(i+1)$. With prob $q$ he loses 1, after which his prob of reaching $N$ is $p(i-1)$. Hence the equation above. Of course, we supplement that with $p(0)=0$ and $p(N)=1$. But there is still quite a lot to do to get an explicit formula.